# OneSignal Push Application getting crashed

Tags: java, android, push-notification, onesignal

I have implemented onesignal as push notification in one of my android application. notification working fine if it have working internet during notification sent time but if device have not internet connection and we send notification, than when user enable internet in device and receive notification than application getting crashed...what is the issue ?

Note : Error Log attached

Thanks

```html
04-10 23:20:12.288: E/OneSignal(16528):  at com.onesignal.BadgeCountUpdater.update(BadgeCountUpdater.java:44)
04-10 23:20:12.288: E/OneSignal(16528):  at com.onesignal.NotificationBundleProcessor.saveNotification(NotificationBundleProcessor.java:111)
04-10 23:20:12.288: E/OneSignal(16528):  at com.onesignal.NotificationBundleProcessor.Process(NotificationBundleProcessor.java:77)
04-10 23:20:12.288: E/OneSignal(16528):  at com.onesignal.GcmIntentService.onHandleIntent(GcmIntentService.java:66)
04-10 23:20:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(16528):  at com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.ShortcutBadger.initBadger(ShortcutBadger.java:92)
04-10 23:20:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(16528):  at com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.ShortcutBadger.applyCountOrThrow(ShortcutBadger.java:65)
04-10 23:20:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(16528):  at com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.ShortcutBadger.applyCount(ShortcutBadger.java:50)
04-10 23:20:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(16528):  at com.onesignal.BadgeCountUpdater.updateCount(BadgeCountUpdater.java:71)
04-10 23:20:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(16528):  at com.onesignal.BadgeCountUpdater.update(BadgeCountUpdater.java:65)
04-10 23:20:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(16528):  at com.onesignal.NotificationBundleProcessor.saveNotification(NotificationBundleProcessor.java:111)
04-10 23:20:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(16528):  at com.onesignal.NotificationBundleProcessor.Process(NotificationBundleProcessor.java:77)
04-10 23:20:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(16528):  at com.onesignal.GcmIntentService.onHandleIntent(GcmIntentService.java:66)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using [version 2.3.0](https://github.com/one-signal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/releases/tag/2.3.0) or later of the OneSignal SDK, this version includes a fix for a Context null error with badges.